Universal Property of Tensor Product of Algebras.
Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $M,N$ be two $A$-modules. A notable property that characterize tensor product is that for any $A$-module $P$, $$\operatorname{Hom}_A(M\otimes_A N,P)\simeq\operatorname{Bil}(M\times N, P)$$where $\operatorname{Bil}(-,P)$ is the $A$-module of all bilinear maps between a product $-$ of two $A$-modules and $P$. Combining with the fact that two modules $M_1,M_2$ are isomorphic iff $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M_1,P)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M_2,P)$ are isomorphic for any $A$-module $P$, one could prove isomorphism results about tensor product of modules very easily without mentioning any concrete construction like "tensors" $m\otimes n$.
I am reading the book by Atiyah and Mcdonald but he used the construction everywhere, including the definition of tensor product of two $A$-algebras. How can I avoid concrete tensors and use the universal property? He did not mention but can anyone tell me the universal property or the adjoint property of tensor product of algebras?

Atiyah-MacDonald uses "algebra" to mean a commutative unital algebra, so in this context the tensor product of algebras is the coproduct in the category of commutative unital $R$-algebras. That is, for $R$-algebras $A,B$ there are natural $R$-algebra homomorphisms $\alpha:A \to A\otimes_R B$ and $\beta:B \to A \otimes_R B$ given by $a \mapsto a\otimes 1_B$ and $b\mapsto 1_A \otimes b$, such that for all $R$-algebras $S$ with $R$-algebra homomorphisms $f:A\to S$ and $g:B \to S$, there exists a unique map $h:A\otimes_R B \to S$ such that $h\circ\alpha = f$ and $h\circ\beta = g$. We encode this in the following diagram:

Note that there is also a concept of tensor product for noncommutative $R$-algebras. In this context, the tensor product is no longer a coproduct.
